# Audio Stream Input blocks get dropped?

Tags: android, sockets, audio, audio-streaming, rtp

I'm trying to send audio through AudioStream from android device to Vlc media player, Vlc catches audio stream but drops all the blocks.
Follwing is a block of code. Is there a problem with codec?[Vlc Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZzzV.png)

```
AudioManager audiomanager =(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
localip= getLocalAddress().toString();
audioStream = new AudioStream(getLocalAddress());
locolport.append(String.valueOf(audioStream.getLocalPort()));
audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
audioStream.associate(remoteIP, 22222);
audioStream.join(audioGroup);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was with permissions of android device, I was requiring permissions in manifest file but in android version Marshmallow or higher I had to request permissions on run time at least once(if granted).